# Can I give a border (outline) to a line in matplotlib plot function?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I try:

```
points = [...]
axe.plot([i[0] for i in points], [i[1] for i in points], linestyle='-', linewidth=10, 
color='black', markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='green')
```

But I just get a black contour. How can I achieve something like on the following picture?
[image: black line with green border]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just plot the line twice with different thicknesses:

```
axe.plot([i[0] for i in points], [i[1] for i in points], linestyle='-', linewidth=10, 
color='green')
axe.plot([i[0] for i in points], [i[1] for i in points], linestyle='-', linewidth=5, 
color='black')
```

Answer (score 87):

If you plot a line twice it won't show up in the legend. It's indeed better to use patheffects. Here are two simple examples:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patheffects as pe

# setup data
x = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
y = np.sin(2*2*np.pi*t)

# create line plot including an outline (stroke) using path_effects
plt.plot(x, y, color='k', lw=2, path_effects=[pe.Stroke(linewidth=5, foreground='g'), pe.Normal()])
# custom plot settings
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim((-2, 2))
plt.legend(['sine'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if you want to add a line shadow

```
# create line plot including an simple line shadow using path_effects
plt.plot(x, y, color='k', lw=2, path_effects=[pe.SimpleLineShadow(shadow_color='g'), pe.Normal()])
# custom plot settings
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim((-2, 2))
plt.legend(['sine'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the path_effects. This even works with collections. Like this:     
t = ax.add_collection(lines)
t.set_path_effects([path_effects.PathPatchEffect(offset=(1,-1), facecolor='gray'), path_effects.PathPatchEffect(edgecolor='white', linewidth=1.1, facecolor='black')])

Comment: Thank you for the example @Mattijn. I tried to add borders to a dashed line but it does not work at the gaps. Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: Beautiful! It even works on text.

Answer (score 5):

The more general answer is to use patheffects.  Easy outlines and shadows (and other things) for any artist rendered with a path.
The matplotlib docs (and examples) are quite accessible.

http://matplotlib.org/users/patheffects_guide.html

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/patheffect_demo.html