# Path Effects for Markers in Matplotlib's Errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, path, effects

I'm trying to include an outline to lines plotted with plt.errorbar(). As suggested by [Can I give a border (outline) to a line in matplotlib plot function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729529/can-i-give-a-border-outline-to-a-line-in-matplotlib-plot-function])\,, I tried to use path_effects, however I need a different path_effect for the markers and the line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as pe

x = np.arange(20)
y = x**1.3

# Two lines.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(x, y, fmt='-o', lw=5, mew=3, ms=5, c='k')
ax.errorbar(x, y, fmt='-o', lw=2, mew=0, ms=5, c='r')

# Single line with path_effects.
y += 10
ax.errorbar(x, y, fmt='-o', lw=2, mew=0, ms=5, c='b',
            path_effects=[pe.Stroke(linewidth=5, foreground='k'), pe.Normal()])
```

which produces the following output:

[image: different outline attemps].

The difference between these methods is that in the former, the outline appears as a constant width around both the line and the marker, while in the one using `path_effects`, the outline is thicker around the markers. Is there a way to adjust the outline linewidth for the marker and the line separately?

Comment: Can you describe more in detail what you do and what you don't like about your output and how exactly the desired output should look like?

Comment: With the 'overlaying' method, to get an outline of constant width I have to make use a `linewidth` that is twice the width of the `markeredgewidth`. With path_effects, I can only work out how to enter a single linewidth argument so the resulting outline around the markers appears to be twice the width of the outline around the line.